# How to count regular expressions used in source code files?

Tags: regex

If we consider a regular expression delimited by " " in X programming language, is there a way to count or get an estimate of how many expressions used as regular expressions contains a code base (this is source code in several files in different directories)?

Comment: Is the delimiter the quoted space or the quotes surrounding it?

Comment: No, it just a way to write delimiters in a readable way ("")

Answer (score 2):

That all depends on your definition of a regular expression ofcourse.

This is a valid regular expression: `stackoverflow`, so by that definition just count the amount of words (delimited by " " in your case) and you're done

Comment: +1 Funny :-) (clearly it's true)... But you could mount a Regex by starting with chars. In C# you could do a 's'.ToString() and that would be a valid RE :-)

Comment: Edited, I want to know how many expressions used as regular expressions, not just strings

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this is relevant, but:

If the regex is just a string delimited by `""` then I would say NO.

If you have e.g. .NET then you can count the `new Regex`. But there are still static functions where you don't need to create a Regex object, then same problem as above ...

Answer (score 0):

for X programming language, no. But if you work for a specific programming language you can always look for operators, functions and objects that are used for regex operations.